# Filter data in Firebase (with complex query) android

Tags: android, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to filter data in `Firebase`. I got some queries but I am unable to filter data as per my requirement.

**Data :**

```
{
  "messages": {
    "Data_1": {
      "Inner_3": {
        "Text": {
          "-Kqgd2_QSi5HIlyH6Om3": {
            "date": 1501840029764,
            "text": "hi"
          },
          "-Kqgd6zZf51AdKNPrsX8": {
            "date": 1501840047829,
            "text": "hello"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Data_2": {
      "Inner_2": {
        "Text": {
          "-Kqm5GijxFT54wZRHIJj": {
            "date": 1.501931572192E9,
            "text": "hi"
          },
          "-Kqm5YohOG1cFWO-WNGc": {
            "date": 1.501931646257E9,
            "text": "test"
          },
          "-Kqm6935IY8Ddj20Z3TN": {
            "date": 1.501931802871E9,
            "text": "new message"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In above json, If I pass `Inner_3` then It should return below result. It checks in all `arrays` if `Inner_3` is available then give me main layer name with last `TEXT` from `Inner_3`.

```
{
  "messages": {
    "Data_1": {
      "Text": {
        "-Kqgd6zZf51AdKNPrsX8": {
          "date": 1501840047829,
          "text": "hello"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me to achieve this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that sort of query is not possible on the Firebase Database. You'll have to change your data structure to accommodate it.

One way is to add the `Inner_3` as the value of a known property:

```
{
  "messages": {
    "Data_1": {
      "Key": "Inner_3"
      "Inner_3": {
        "Text": {
          "-Kqgd2_QSi5HIlyH6Om3": { "date": 1501840029764, "text": "hi" },
          "-Kqgd6zZf51AdKNPrsX8": { "date": 1501840047829, "text": "hello" }
        }
      }
    },
    "Data_2": {
      "Key": "Inner_2"
      "Inner_2": {
        "Text": {
          "-Kqm5GijxFT54wZRHIJj": { "date": 1.501931572192E9, "text": "hi" },
          "-Kqm5YohOG1cFWO-WNGc": { "date": 1.501931646257E9, "text": "test" },
          "-Kqm6935IY8Ddj20Z3TN": { "date": 1.501931802871E9, "text": "new message" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can query with:

```
ref.child("messages").orderByChild("Key").equalTo("Inner_3")
```

Alternatively you can add a separate lookup list:

```
"InnerToNodeNameMapping": {
  "Inner_3": "Data_1",
  "Inner_2": "Data_2"
}
```

Then you can find the path of the `Inner_3` item by a direct lookup:

```
ref.child("InnerToNodeNameMapping").child("Inner_3")
```

And from that you can directly access the node (no query needed).

Having to adapt/expand your data structure to allow the use-cases that you want in your app is very common on Firebase and other NoSQL databases. Since you seem relatively new to NoSQL, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

Comment: Thank you so much. What if Data_2 contains Inner_2 and Inner_3 both ? then, what should I use in Key ?

Comment: That turns into a categorization problem. See my longer answer on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: As per your link suggestion, I created different channel for listing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to order by key .orderByKey(), and get the lastone, rember firebase pushed keys ar random strings that contain timestamp inside.

The most common ordering method is ref.orderByKey(). It orders the ref’s children by their keys, usually push keys — which order by time.

After you have your snapshot ordered by key you can do something like this:

```
var firstdata;
 snapshot.forEach(function(mySnapshot) {
  if (!firstdata) {
  firstdata = mySnapshot.val();
   }
  });
  console.log(firstdata);
```

Comment: `.orderByKey()` is fine but main issue is to find 'Inner_3' from all upper layers.

Comment: I am already doing this. But what if I have 10000s of messages then I think it is not good option to fetch all data and filter it my side.

Comment: I understand, firebase is not thought to do that, the only workaround to do this is looping each elemnt and getting the last one, or storing the pushed keys in a path like /times and you retrieve from there the last key and the path where it store the text.